# Activate the Touch Keyboard on a RaspberryPi3 (Win IoT 10 Core) with an UWP

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, multitouch-keyboard

I have created a UWP on the Raspberry Pi3 Win 10 IoT Core and want to enter data into a text box using Touch Keyboard. Does anyone have a clue how to activate the Touch Keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option of showing the on-screen keyboard on [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal). Please check the item 'Show the on-screen keyboard when text input controls have focus' on Device Setting tab.

[image]